# Python pygame error : Failed loading libpng.dylib: dlopen(libpng.dylib, 2): image not found

Tags: python, macos, libpng

I installed the FlapPyBird repo from https://github.com/sourabhv/FlapPyBird. I have libpng installed but when i try to run the program with python flappy.py i get

```
Failed loading libpng.dylib: dlopen(libpng.dylib, 2): image not found
```

Any ideas about whats wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What is the output when you run `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in Terminal? (It should be empty.)

Comment: Because it could be that your DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH was set permanently -- for example, in your ~/.bash_profile -- which is [almost always an indication that you are doing something wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24964138/3345375).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you must install `libpng`?

You can do it with homebrew:

```
brew install libpng
```

Comment: Tried that. That doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use python3 interpreter and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
brew unlink libpng && brew link libpng
```

With me it was some problems with the linking.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Installing the following with homebrew fixed it:

```
brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf portmidi
```

Got the info from here:

http://brysonpayne.com/2015/01/10/setting-up-pygame-on-a-mac/