# Why am I getting this Pygame Error: Failed to start CoreAudio

Tags: python, macos, pygame

Now, can you please help me with this error? I'm doing a game with Python and Pygame. It runs perfectly on my desktop Windows PC, but when I try it on my Macbook, the following error surges:

```
pygame.mixer.init()
  pygame.error: Failed to start CoreAudio: AudioUnitSetProperty (kAudioUnitPropoerty_SetInputCallback)
```

I have been looking for this problem here, but have not found a solution.
PD: Obviously the Python and Pygame versions are the same in my desktop PC and in mi Macbook.

Comment: Maybe Python and Pygame are the same but they use other things like C/C++ libraries (ie. SDL) which use other elements (etc.) and they can be different on different system :/ It hard to say anything. Try to find the same error message in Google.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  To make it easier for people to understand and reproduce your problem please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the error message was a good start.

Comment: Thanks you both.
I finally just fixed the issue. I reinstalled Pygame, and then installed this
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40295704/7170497). Now it works :)