# OSX PyGame Failed loading libpng.dylib: dlopen(libpng.dylib, 2)

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I'm getting this error `pygame.error: Failed loading libpng.dylib: dlopen(libpng.dylib, 2): image not found` when running a program on OSX (10.11.6) using Python 2.7

I've tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645391/python-pygame-error-failed-loading-libpng-dylib-dlopenlibpng-dylib-2-imag) but I've had no luck and I can't seem to find much else on this issue. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the output when you run `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in Terminal? (It should be empty.)

Comment: Because it could be that your DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH was set permanently -- for example, in your ~/.bash_profile -- which is [almost always an indication that you are doing something wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24964138/3345375).

Comment: @jkdev I have no output when running that

Comment: OK, so that isn't the issue.

Comment: Is libpng installed on your system? (Run a Finder search for Name matches: libpng)

Comment: No it's not. I will install it now Edit: It was already installed but was outdated. I updated it via brew and the error still persists.

Answer (score -1):

Use python3 interpreter in terminal
e.g. python3  xx.py